# Making a HTML link to a JavaScript Array for a JS Slider

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, linker, slider

So I want to create links in my website to link to an array in script.js file which is where I contain my JavaScript for the content slider I've created.

**The idea is to click a link from this html:**

```html
    <div id="slider">
      <h2 id="sliderHeader">Social Determinants of Health</h2>
      <p>______________________</p>
      <p id="sliderPara">In terms of health - good quality health care is a determinant of health, and access, affordability, and acceptability of health are all socially determined. But most social determinants of health lie outside the health care system.</p>
      <a href="#"><input class="readmore_button" type="submit" value="Read more" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slider_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Social Determinants of Health</a></li>
        <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Monitoring Progress</a></li>
        <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">What Works</a></li>
        <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Making it Happen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

To link to one of my arrays which is a separate slider. **As seen below:**

```js
var headArray= ['Social Determinants of Health',
'Monitoring Progress',
'What Works',
'Making it Happen'];
```

Is this even possible? If not is there a workaround?

p.s. this is the website I'm working on http://hghazni.com/ihe/

Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't you simply use `onclick` for the spans, and pass the index of the related array item?

Comment: Hey Jim, I'm with you on the onclick solution which I'm playing around with but unsure on the comment about passing the index for the related array. I'm going to be honest, I'm not great at JavaScript so I'm learning a lot as I'm going a long.

Comment: Should I create a new function for each slider and just simply link them with an onclick?

Comment: I am a bit confused. You have an array full of links and a list of anchors that need to be tied to a specific index in your array? Do I have that correct?

Comment: No I need to make a specific link to the array with anchor tags for each individual anchor (as they're all slides in a slider). Since I want to be able to have on the HTML page a link users can click to access each of those anchor tags which will choose that specific slide if that makes sense. Sorry I'm probably awful at explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just made a function for each value in the array variable which reset the slider count and slider interval time. Then grabbed the relevant element id's.

```js
function slider_link_1() {
  cnt = 0;
  timer = setInterval(slider, 5000);
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'" + imgadr[cnt] + "\')";
  document.getElementById('sliderHeader').innerHTML = headArray[0];
  document.getElementById('sliderPara').innerHTML = paraArray[0];
}

function slider_link_2() {
  cnt = 1;
  timer = setInterval(slider, 5000);
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'" + imgadr[cnt] + "\')";
  document.getElementById('sliderHeader').innerHTML = headArray[1];
  document.getElementById('sliderPara').innerHTML = paraArray[1];
}

function slider_link_3() {
  cnt = 2;
  timer = setInterval(slider, 5000);
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'" + imgadr[cnt] + "\')";
  document.getElementById('sliderHeader').innerHTML = headArray[2];
  document.getElementById('sliderPara').innerHTML = paraArray[2];
}

function slider_link_4() {
  cnt = 3;
  timer = setInterval(slider, 5000);
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'" + imgadr[cnt] + "\')";
  document.getElementById('sliderHeader').innerHTML = headArray[3];
  document.getElementById('sliderPara').innerHTML = paraArray[3];
}
```

Then I ended up linking them on my index.html like **this:**

```html
<div class="slider_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="slider_link_1()">Social Determinants of Health</a>
    </li>
    <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="slider_link_2()">Monitoring Progress</a>
    </li>
    <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="slider_link_3()">What Works</a>
    </li>
    <li><span style="color:#fff;">|</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="slider_link_4()">Making it Happen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And now it works! That was hard, but I learnt a lot! Thanks to the people who pointed me in the right direction for me to figure it out myself.

**Live version here:** http://hghazni.com/ihe

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! I always feel better coming to my own solution. Some notes on how you could optimize it: Notice that all four functions use the same code, but different values for `cnt` (and also that the array indices are the same as `cnt`. You could change your `onclick`s to call a single method, passing in a value, like: `onclick="slider_link(0)"`. Then in your JavaScript, you'd have one function like: `function slider_link(index) { ... }`. You can then use `index` as the value for the array indices.